# Anonymous access of method from Jersey webservice which is secured with spring security and oAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, jersey-2.0, jersey-client, spring-security-oauth2

I have one Jersey Rest web service which handles person account CRUD.
I have spring security+ oAuth2 to secure this api , what i am not able to configure is , i wanted to make  anonymous of Account create method. i tried to configure intercept url but it does not work method level. so do i need to write separate class for this purpose or i can achieve without it.

Sample class code

```
public class AccountResource{

createAccount() --- I want this method to be accessed by Anonymous uers so they can create account without generating tokens.
updateAccount() --
findAccount() --
deleteAccont()--

}
```

Config code which makes secure all calls starting '/services/rest/**'

```
<http pattern="/services/rest/**" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/services/rest/**" method="GET" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/services/rest/**" method="POST" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/services/rest/**" method="PUT" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/services/rest/**" method="DELETE" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "intercept url ... does not work method level"? Is your Jersey resource a Spring Bean?

Comment: Please also add your spring security config.

Comment: i mean the method which add new account should not be secured.

Comment: @FritzDuchardt, My security with Spring + oAuth2 working fine, i just want to allow user to create new Account without any security/token.             Yes Jersey resource is spring bean.

Comment: @DaveSyer, Yes Jersey resource is spring bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing the configuration for POST requests in your security config to:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/services/rest/**" access="permitAll" method="POST" />
```

Comment: I have added as <intercept-url pattern="/services/rest/Accounts"  method="POST" access="permitAll" />  and when i make post request it throws exceptions as : Caused by:  {
error: "unauthorized"
error_description: "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"
}

Comment: did you try without the anonymous tag?

Comment: Do you mean   <anonymous enabled="true"  /> ?

Comment: Thanks, It's working with anonymous  but it throwing exception with other http methods : org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'ROLE_USER' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot' - maybe not public?

Comment: try access="isFullyAuthenticated()"  instead of access="ROLE_USER"

Comment: Thanks @Fritz , it worked, but not sure why it was not working with access='ROLE_USER'